# Login google Auth in expo not working properly

Tags: react-native, expo, google-authentication

when i press the sign in with google button it doesn't do anything

i followed https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google/

the iosClientId: 'my-id', is normally my google clientid but changed it for security reasons

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';

class LoginScreen extends Component {
    async signInWithGoogleAsync () {
        try {
            const result = await Expo.Google.logInAsync({
                //androidClientId: YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE,
                behavior: 'web',
                iosClientId: 'my-id',
                scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
            });

            if (result.type === 'success') {
                return result.accessToken;
            } else {
                return { cancelled: true };
            }
        } catch (e) {
            return { error: true };
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Button title={"Sign In With Google"}
                 onpress={() =>this.signInWithGoogleAsync()}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
export default LoginScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
    }
});
```

I expect is when i press the Sign In With Google button it to let me sign in

but what im getting is the button not doing anything

Comment: The `signInWithGoogleAsync` function looks good. I think the issue here is that you have a typo in your Button. Instead of `onpress`, it should be `onPress`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your render function to this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button title={"Sign In With Google"}
             onPress={() =>this.signInWithGoogleAsync()}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```